# Cannot find symbol after loop body

Tags: java, loops, compiler-errors

So got this code where I want to print out the final sum of the equation but I get this error that said...

```
Test.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(amount);
                       ^
symbol:   variable amount
location: class Test
```

Is this because it's out of scope? Not really sure what's that problem here.

```
public class Test{
 public static void main(String[]args){
    double p = 1000;
    double r = 0.1;
    double t = 5;
    double amount;

    for(int a = 0; a < t; a++){
        amount = p * (1 + r*t);
        p = amount;
    }
    System.out.println(amount);
 }
}
```

Comment: Declare `double amount` _before_ the start of the `for` loop.

Comment: `amount` is local to your `for` loop

Comment: yes it is because it is out of scope. Not sure what is the point of `amount` as you are just assigning the value to `p`. In this case you can just do `p = p * (1 + r * t)` and print out `p`

Comment: Get your terminology straight. The code hasn't even compiled yet, let alone executed.

Answer (score 4):

`amount` is declared inside the loop, so it cannot be accessed outside the loop. I would read about [variable scope in Java](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). See the part about "loop scope"

> Any variables created inside of a loop are LOCAL TO THE LOOP. This means that once you exit the loop, the variable can no longer be accessed! This includes any variables created in the loop signature.

Read more: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html#ixzz4gjHz61kY

You would fix it by declaring `amount` outside of the loop.

```
double amount = 0d;
for(int a = 0; a < t; a++){
    amount = p * (1 + r*t);
    p = amount;
}
System.out.println(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives compile time error - "Local Variable May not have been initialized".

You have to initialize the variable before using it.

Local Variable(Variable in method) wont get default value, we have to initialize it explicitly.

Note: Only instance variable(Variables in class ) gets default value.